# Python randomly generated walks give same outcome when graphed

Tags: python, loops, random, random-walk

```
from pylab import *

no_steps = 10000

number = random()
position = zeros(no_steps)
position[0] = 0
time = zeros(no_steps)
time[0] = 0

for i in range(1, no_steps):
    time[i] = time[i-1] + 1
    if number >= 0.5:
        position[i] = position[i-1] + 1
        number = random()
    else:
        position[i] = position[i-1] - 1
        number = random()
plot(time, position)

number2 = random()
position2 = zeros(no_steps)
position2[0] = 0
time2 = zeros(no_steps)
time2[0] = 0
for t2 in range(1, no_steps):
    time2[t2] = time[t2-1] + 1
    if number2 >= 0.5:
        position2[t2] = position2[t2-1] + 1
        number2 = random()
    else:
        position2[t2] = position[t2-1] - 1
        number2 = random()
plot(time2,position2)
```

This is supposed to generate random walks by generating a random number each time and checking the conditions. Therefore I assumed that if it works for one walk I can just add more of the same and put them all on the same graph at the end. However, apparently that's not how this works and the graphs that do end up being plotted are extremely similar with the difference in the positions being one of -2 for some reason. The code if I run the blocks separately from their own program will generate two completely different walks, it's just when I put them together that it stops working as intended. What exactly am I missing?

Comment: Fix this line: `position2[t2] = position[t2-1] - 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've accidentally reused variables from the first plot:

```
for t2 in range(1, no_steps):
    time2[t2] = time[t2-1] + 1
    ^^^^^       ^^^^
    if number2 >= 0.5:
        position2[t2] = position2[t2-1] + 1
        number2 = random()
    else:
        position2[t2] = position[t2-1] - 1
        ^^^^^^^^^       ^^^^^^^^
        number2 = random()
plot(time2,position2)
```

I would generate the random walk with a function so you don't have to worry about renaming variables like this:

```
import numpy
from pylab import *

no_steps = 10000

def random_walk(no_steps):
    # 2 * [0, 1] - 1  ->  [0, 2] - 1  ->  [-1, 1]
    directions = 2 * numpy.random.randint(0, 2, size=(1, no_steps)) - 1
    positions = numpy.cumsum(directions)
    positions -= positions[0]  # To make it start from zero

    return positions

time1 = numpy.arange(0, no_steps)
plot(time1, random_walk(no_steps))
savefig('1.png')

clf()

time2 = numpy.arange(0, no_steps)
plot(time2, random_walk(no_steps))
savefig('2.png')
```

Comment: Lifesaver, I could have continued staring at it for the next couple of hours and not seen it. Thank you very much.

Comment: @user490418: If you're interested in how to do this without renaming variables, I've added a function to my answer that generates the random walk quickly.